# ASP.NET MVC - Missing "Convert to Web Application" option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, webforms

I created a new MVC project and added some webforms pages to it in an effort to start adding new pages to my app using MVC and eventually port the old pages over as well. Everything is building and working correctly but I did notice that I don't have the "Convert to Web Application" option when right clicking an aspx file.  And I think its not regenerating my designer files when I change the controls on a page.

My guess is that the ProjectTypeGuid is wrong or in the wrong order.  Can someone confirm?

Old (Webforms) project file

```
<ProjectGuid>{4F95C3D9-228E-4BD5-9840-46224BA3EBA7}</ProjectGuid>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

New (MVC) project file

```
<ProjectGuid>{A4690D3F-695B-4BF4-93B7-EA5B17793051}</ProjectGuid>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{603c0e0b-db56-11dc-be95-000d561079b0};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so wrong on so many levels but I am going to answer you anyways in the hopes I might get an uptick or something. You have two routes with this. First route which I use all the time is put your mvc applications in their own projects. When your deploying the site drop the webforms application first, and then make a folder in that webforms application and put your mvc application into that folder. That should work like a charm for you. If you insit on having webforms and MVC Framework in the same project, then don't drop your webforms into the view folder. Create its own folder because you can not directly access your aspx pages from the views folder without making modifications to the web.config. Hope this helps.

Comment: My webform pages are not in the view folder.  They are in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is available as a Web Project only. The VS2005 style Web Site is not supported.